# Is there a way to load a flask route based on the url

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

So I have a Flask app and there's basically two versions of the URL: `example.com/` and `example.com/MhkQV`

But the ending(MhkQV) will be randomized based on a database. (It could be hDjnY for example)

Can I load a certain flask route if `example.com/MhkQV` is sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can accept random values like 'MhkQV', Here I am using the name variable which accepts any random value just after '/'. and you may use this value inside your function or just for redirecting your URL.

```
@app.route('/<name>')
def hello_name(name):
    return "Hello {}!".format(name)
```